# How to make connection over WiFi when working with Gamekit?

Tags: ios, wifi, p2p, gamekit

I want to make connection between two devices over WiFi using GameKit. Apple's documentation says

> If an Internet connection is chosen, your application must dismiss the peer picker dialog and present its own user interface to complete the connection.

This is what i do

```
- (void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker didSelectConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type
{
if (type == GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline) 
{
    picker.delegate = nil;
    [picker dismiss];
    [picker autorelease];

    [alert setTitle:@"\n\n\n"];
    [alert setMessage:@"Looking for other iPads, iPhones or iPod touches..."];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *progress   = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
    progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    [alert addSubview:progress];
    [progress startAnimating];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

Ok, i have presented my own interface. And what next? How do i connect? How to start looking for peers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1) builds peer to peer card game using Gamekit and either Bluetooth or wifi. (link updated)

Comment: The link is wrong - it goes to an ADVERT for the tutorial. Actual tutorial is here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1